# Proving this element-wise multiplication operator in $l^2$ is a closed operator, but not continuous.

Tags: solution-verification, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

I was reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2353604/closed-linear-operators-vs-continuous-linear-operators) maths stack exchange post about the difference between closed and continuous linear operators.

The example given there is that the operator defined on $l^2$ by $T(x):=(x_1,2x_2,...,nx_n,...)$ is closed but not continuous.

For this operator I would like to show that

(a) It is closed.

(b) That it is not continuous.

I'd like help in showing (a) and (b).

I noticed however that in the linked post it was not declared the domain $D(T)\subseteq l^2$ of $T$.

I took a guess and assumed that the most natural choice of domain for $T$ was one which it's image made sense in $l^2$;

$$D(T)= \{ x \in l^2 : ||T(x)||^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |n x_n|^2 < \infty \}$$

However I am not sure if this is was the intended domain or not..

Here is my attempt.

(a)

To show closed lets assume $x^k \to x \in l^2$ and $Tx^k \to y \in l^2$ for $(x^k)_k \subset D(T)$ a squence. For (a) it is enough to show that (i) $x \in D(T)$ and (ii) $Tx=y$.

Well for (i) I just show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |n x_n|^2$ is finite, by a variant of Minkowski's inequality we have

\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{n=1}^N |n x_n|^2\right)^\frac{1}{2} &\leq \left(\sum_{n=1}^N |n x_n-nx_n^k|^2\right)^\frac{1}{2} + \left(\sum_{n=1}^N |nx_n^k|^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}
\newline
&\leq N\left(\sum_{n=1}^N |x_n-x_n^k|^2\right)^\frac{1}{2} + \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty|nx_n^k|^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}
\newline
&\leq N||x-x^k||+||Tx^k||
\end{align*}
Where the last line follows since each $x^k$ is in $D(T)$.
Now since $x^k \to x$ in $l^2$ we may make $||x-x^k||<N^{-1}$ for suitably large $k$. Hence taking the limit $k \to \infty$ gives

$$ \left(\sum_{n=1}^N |n x_n|^2\right)^\frac{1}{2} \leq 1+ ||y||$$
for all $N\in \mathbb{N}$.

Hence the sequence of partial sums is bounded above and strictly increasing and hence convergent. So $x \in D(T)$ this is (i).

For (ii) I am much less sure, I would like to show $||x-Tx_n|| \to 0$ but this seems very close to showing that $T$ is continuous which I know it shouldn't be as mentioned in the linked stack exchange post.

(b)

To show $T$ is not continuous I am also struggling.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: (b) You can take $x_n=(0,0,...,0,1/n,0,...)$. Then $\|x_n\|=1/n\to0$, but $\|T(x_n)\|=1\not\to0$. (a) You can see that it is self-adjoint and therefore closed.

Comment: Yep, that'll do it - thanks!

Comment: Sorry after some time I'm not able to edit my. Comment - Yep, that'll do part (b) - thanks! Doesn't the operator need to be densely defined for T* to be defined?

Comment: The domain, well the maximum domain of definition, contains all elements of $\ell^2$ with finitely many non-zero components. For any $x\in\ell^2$, the sequence $x_n$ formed by zeroing all components after the $n$-th one satisfy $\|x-x_n\|^2=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}|x^{(k)}-x_n^{(k)}|\to0$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, apologies I've not progressed far enough in my operator theory course to make much sense of your comment. I would of thought the maximal domain of definition is the one I'd given in my question, the domain you mention certainly is contained in mine. The question of an operator being closed or not is dependent, in part, on its domain. I'm not sure which domain the authors in the linked post intended. If it is the one mentioned in your previous comment then fair enough your method would work, but does it show the operator with domain mentioned in my question is closed?

Comment: Yes, the maximal domain of definition is the set that you mentioned. The one that I said is a subset of it, and what followed the explanation of why this subset is dense. Therefore, the domain is dense too.

Comment: Ah yes I understand. Thank you for your answer. If you'd be willing to write your comments up as an answer I'd be happy to accept it.